# Sending a SMS from KDE Connect in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, gui, sms, kde-connect

I set up KDE Connect on Kubuntu 18.04. Ping and the File Explorer are working fine from the desktop. I am able to recieve, read and respond to SMS. However, I have no clue how I can send an SMS, when I try to start the process from the desktop:

[image]

This is my current verions of kdeconnect listed by `dpkg -l`

```
ii  kdeconnect                                      1.3.1-0ubuntu0.1                                  amd64        connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma Workspace
```

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue; did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: no, i just lived with it. sorry

Comment: @jan-seins looks like there are different indicator implementations. Following link from your reply to answer below i installed indicator-kdeconnect and it behaves like in the article, with "Send SMS" in menu. But it requires sync with android app via google account to get contacts to send SMS to, so i didn't test further. Maybe this google account requirement is the reason it is not included in ubuntu? What about FDroids?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an application that can be used to do this, which I call kdecsms.

It solves a problem I have had for a long time which is that there is no tool that can be started by Thunderbird Cardbook that will open a dialog to send SMS messages.

It is written in pyqt5 and is simple to install. You can see it at [kdecsms](https://github.com/mgolden/kdecsms) - any comments or suggestions would be appreciated, as would any ideas about how to get it distributed with kdeconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the applet in the top-right of your screen on Ubuntu. You’ll see the options that are available with KDE Connect. One of them allows you to send a text message. Select that and a **Compose SMS** window will appear.

There are two boxes: One for the number of the recipient and one for the message. Compose the text message, and send it. Note that kde connect and Ubuntu just pass the message to your phone, which does all the work.

Comment: I am just missing that option to send a sms all I have is the ping and browse file Options. In this artcile there is a menu point "send sms". However I am missing this one. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-send-sms-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 and there is no Send SMS option, and the WebUpd8 ppa crashes with `Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket`

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing because there are two indicators with `kde-connect`

One only appeared after I enabled SMS on both PC & phone and then sent an SMS to myself

[image: Two indicators]

One of the indicators has Send SMS and the other doesnt

Comment: Pressing `Send SMS` did not pop up anything